# Relocate option is not showing on SVN Repositories

Tags: svn, smartsvn

I want to relocate my repository but on right click "Relocate" option is not there.
I tried many time but didn't get any solution so please resolve this issue also check the attached screen shot.
hope to hear from you soon thank you
[image]

Comment: Can't you drop to the commandline? http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.c.relocate.html

Comment: Relocate is available on a folder from a working copy, not in the repository browser.

Comment: In Subversion, the relocate command is used to update the repository path in a given working copy when such path has changed. It doesn't move the repository itself. In fact, it's a pure client-side feature.